# Is there a way to off a jquery event then on it again?

Tags: jquery

I've added an event listener like this:

```
$('body').on('mouseenter','.classname',function() { /* code */ });
```

Then I've removed it like this:

```
$('.classname').off('mouseenter');
```

Now I'd like to turn it on again. I've tried this:

```
$('.classname').on('mouseenter');
```

...but it didn't work.

**How can I do it?**

Comment: why not do $('body').on('mouseenter','.classname',function() { /* code */ }); again ?

Comment: Updated my response-- I'm surprised 'body' is a valid listener; I can't get it to work in Chrome. You're probably better off with $(document) if you just want a "listen everywhere" listener; otherwise find an even closer ancestor like some sort of wrapper div.

Answer (score 7):

Not like that, no. When you off it, you are destroying the event. It's not stored in memory as something that can just be reactivated like that. There are easy ways to simplify the mouseenter binding call, though.

Or, just use a flag in the mouseenter logic. If the flag is true, go ahead and do the rest of the stuff; otherwise, do nothing. The flag can easily be set by any other activity on your page.

Really simplified example of the flag method: http://jsfiddle.net/8YXFB/

```
var ontastic = true;

$(document).on('mouseenter', '.classname', function() {
    if (ontastic) {
        $('#output').append('<li>Moused!</li>');
    }
});

$('#on').click(function() {
  ontastic = true;
});

$('#off').click(function() {
  ontastic = false;
});
```

(and the HTML, though you can probably figure it out without)

```
<div class="classname">Mouse me!</div>
<button id="on">MouseEnter On</button><br/>
<button id="off">MouseEnter Off</button>
<ul id="output">
    <li>Initialized</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Store the event listener in a variable instead of declaring it as an anonymous function, then reuse that:

```
var mouseenterListener = function() { /* code */ };
$('body').on('mouseenter', '.classname', mouseenterListener);
$('.classname').off('mouseenter');
// on again
$('body').on('mouseenter', '.classname', mouseenterListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the remainder of your code?

Try removing the "body". Here's a code that works:

```
$('.classname').on('mouseenter', testFunc);

$('.on').click(function(){
  $('.classname').on('mouseenter', testFunc);
  console.log($('.classname').data('events'));

});

$('.off').click(function(){
  $('.classname').off('mouseenter');
  console.log($('.classname').data('events'));
});

var testFunc = function() {};
```

Comment: on and off are just the new syntax for bind and unbind. This doesn't help answer the question.

Comment: He's delegating `'body'` as the listener, which replicates `live()` or `delegate()` functionality. That's not the issue here, though I think there are usually more efficient listeners than `body`. ;-)

Comment: Attaching it to the body doesn't work at all. It just throws an error in the jQuery source. I'm still quite not sure what the end-result is by using the body element to delegate.

Comment: Oh, you're right! I assumed without testing that it would work. I know that $(document) is a valid delegate, but body is not a node in the DOM I guess; you can't select it in that case. Good catch. As for the end result; by having document listening, you can modify the DOM as you see fit and you don't lose events with self-listeners (in this case, `classname` listening for click on itself). If your DOM isn't dynamic it doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the other way around: instead of removing (unbinding) the event, I would create a global flag indicating whether the event should do something or not:

```
var mef = true;

$('body').on('mouseenter', '.classname', function() {
              if (mef) {
             /* code */
             }
 });
```

Thus, anytime you don't want the event to happen, you just make mef = false and to get back the event, mef = true.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, rewrite it like this:

```
$('body').off('mouseenter').on('mouseenter','.classname',function() { /* code */ });
```